# How to un-hide the coupon in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: woocommerce, coupon

There is a link right under the checkout header on Woocommerce that says "Click here to enter your code".  When you click it, a javascript slides the billing details box down to show the coupon code box and "apply coupon" button.

I am trying to make this show automatically on the page load.

The other option is to change the javascript from a click action to a page load action.

Answer (score 6):

Write in your custom CSS:

```
.checkout_coupon {
 display: block !important;
}

.woocommerce-info {
display:none;
}
```